# How long after I submit a piece of spam to SpamCop.net before it gets added to the blacklist?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, blacklist, spamcop

How long after I submit a piece of spam to SpamCop.net before it gets added to the blacklist? [I've been submitting mail here.](http://www.spamcop.net/) but I can't seem to find anything about the process.

- Does the spammer have a chance to reply before they get added to the black list?
- Does it generally take hours, days, weeks or months?

I've just been sending a bunch of spam messages to SpamCop and I'm wondering what the process looks like up until the point that the sender gets blacklisted.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question belongs on ServerFault or not, feel free to migrate it. SpamCop.net is a webapp interface to the SpamCop blacklist http://forum.spamcop.net/scwik/SpamAssassin.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hard-and-fast rule of when it gets added to the blacklist.

SpamCop uses a complicated, intentionally obscure weighting system (details in [SpamCop FAQ item "What is on the list?"](http://www.spamcop.net/fom-serve/cache/297.html) Briefly (and oversimplifying), your report(s) alone will not result in a spam source to be added to the list, it takes others to report, as well, and the spam reports must exceed a level which (if I understand correctly) is proportional to the total volume of mail sent from the outgoing e-mail host.

The list is entirely automatic and the spammer will not have a chance to reply before being added.